# sudo : wildcard in user/group name

Tags: regex, sudo

I try to find a solution about a sudo problem.

I need to push different sudoers files on different servers, depending on the users present on the servers. But I would like to know if I can avoid that and put a single sudoers file everywhere.

for example:

some servers have several group ending with "-dv-grp", and some servers have group ending with "-pa-grp"

It would be so nice if I can put wild card on group name like that:

```
%*-grp ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/vi
```

but it's not working, even if I set a `User_Alias` (I also tried with simple and double quote)....and I can't put all these groups on a single master group (for security reason on my infra).

if it's really not possible I will create different group on put them on these different groups, but I will need to manage different versions of the sudoers file.....and I would like to avoid that

Can you confirm it's not possible? any idea?

Comment: Don't know if possible, but allowing `sudo /usr/bin/vi` is risky and practically results in giving those users full root permissions.  They can simply run `sudo /usr/bin/vi` and in vi type `:!/bin/sh` to get a root shell.

Comment: Hi, Vi is just an example, I don't want to give vi usage. thx

Comment: Wildcards are not possible for user/group names. I think from the security aspect using wildcards in user/group names is a bit risky.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't multiple lines as follows do the trick?

```
%g1-dv-grp           server1=(ALL)                   NOPASSWD: some_commands
%g1-pa-grp           server2=(ALL)                   NOPASSWD: some_commands
%g2-pa-grp           server3=(ALL)                   NOPASSWD: some_commands
```

Yuu still need lines for each server/group combination (so not as neat as wildcards) but does mean that you can have a single sudoers file across all machines.

Comment: Well my initial goal was to not have to edit sudoer file when a new group is created....Anyway I think I will not have the choice...thx